# Get original raised exception in RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, backgroundworker

I'm using background workers in my wcf project in order to handle asynchroneous web services.

Here's how I'm initializing the worker :

```
 worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(RunWorkerCompleted);
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

To handle errors, I have to raise exceptions in my DoWork method... Like this:

```
throw new WebFaultException<MyAsyncResult>(
    new MyAsyncResult("Description of the error"),
    HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
);
```

Finally, I get this exception in RunWorkerCompleted:

```
void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Error == null))
    {
        < Do something with e.Error >
    }
    else
    ...
}
```

**My problem:**

The e.Error I get does not seem to be the orignal Exception I've raised! Indeed, I can't cast it as a WebFaultException and it misses the 'MyAsyncResult' object I'have passed as parameter. Had any of you have this kind of problem ?

Comment: Has `e.Error` an `InnerException`?

Comment: Have you actually checked to what type of object e.Error does contain?

Comment: @JeffRSon The e.Error as no InnerException

Comment: @Will Dean (e.Error is WebFaultException) is false. But e.Error.GetType().Name gives "WebFaultException`1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast e.Error into `WebFaultException<MyAsyncResult>`! The non-generic `WebFaultException` is another thing.